# How can I auto generate standard code for getters and setters and constructors in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I created a class in C# with Visual Studio containing a bunch of variables.
How can I auto-generate Constructors, getters and setters for them?
I know such features from other programming software for developing in Java like Android Studio and Eclipse and I don't find this feature in Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you just wanting to know how to auto-generate something like: `public string Name { get; set; }`  ?

Comment: In the editor, type the word "prop" and hit tab, it will auto-generate the property template, do the same for constructors by typing ctor and tab.

Comment: Visual Studio approaches it from different angle, it has nice feature of generating properties or private member based on constructor arguments. When cursor on the constructor argument `Ctrl`+`.` (or Quick fix) and select `Create and initialize field/property...`

Comment: Thx to all answers:) My solution was to press ctrl + shift + f for searching  for ';' and replacing all with '{ get; set; }'  like Lews Therin wrote and also all 'private' with 'public'

Answer (score 3):

### [Auto Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)

This:

```
public string TestString { get; set; }
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
private string _testString;

public string TestString
{
    get
    {
        return _testString;
    }
    set
    {
        _testString = value;
    }
}
```

### [Code snippets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2017)

If you are using Visual Studio, you can use code snippets to generate boilerplate code for you.

Type `ctor` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. It will generate a parameterless constructor for the class you are currently in.

Type `prop` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Then type the datatype you want your property to be and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice. Finally, type the name of the property and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> one last time. It will generate an auto implemented property for you.

Comment: That full one you listed is the `propfull` snippet (sometimes you do need the whole thing!). Also, IIRC you hit tab *twice* to start